# Parse.com Blocking Mailchimp?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, httprequest, parse-cloud-code

I'm attempting to make an http request to mailchimp to add subscribers, but I seem to be receiving 403 forbidden errors. I've reached out to Mailchimp and it seems to be an issue with Parse. Has anyone experienced a similar issue? If so, did you solve it? Here's my cloud function:

Note: I'm using Mailchimp's latest API (Also it was working smoothly about a week ago):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("reserveSpot", function(request, response) {

    //Check that parameters are being provided
    if (!request.params || !request.params.emailAddress || !request.params.firstName || !request.params.lastName) {

        //Return Response
        response.error("In order to save you a spot we're gonna need your name and email address.");
        return;
    }

    //Retrieve Parameters
    var firstName = request.params.firstName;
    var lastName = request.params.lastName;
    var emailAddress = request.params.emailAddress;
    var inviter = request.params.inviter;
    var recruiter = request.params.recruiter;

    //Define Subscriber
    var subscriber = JSON.stringify({
        "email_address": emailAddress,
        "status": "subscribed",
        "merge_fields": {
            "FNAME": firstName,
            "LNAME": lastName,
            "INVITER": inviter,
            "RECRUITER": recruiter
        }
    });

    //Create POST Request
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<listID>/members',
      body: subscriber,
      headers:
        {
            'Authorization': 'apikey XXXXXXXX',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {

       //Log Data
       console.log("Success: " + httpResponse.text);
       response.success(httpResponse.text);

    }, function(httpResponse) {

       //Log Error
       console.error('Full Error: ' + JSON.stringify(httpResponse));

       //Return Response
       response.error(httpResponse.text);
    });
});
```